# How to take a screenshot on Android 4.4.2 on a Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, screenshots

I read that you need to hold the volume down button and power button simultaneously to take a screenshot. I've tried this many times and I just can't get it to work. Most of the time the volume lowers, sometimes the screen locks.

**Update:** Sometimes it's very easy to take screenshots, but usually it's impossible. It's likely a hardware or software defect. Many times I'm also unable to unlock the screen on my Nexus 4. I'm confident it's not a timing issue.

Comment: Are you pressing both buttons at the same time

Comment: @sameer to the best of my abilities. Maybe there's a few milliseconds delay between pressing both buttons, but I try to press them at the same time.

Comment: I really hope stock Android gets a more convenient and discoverable way of taking screenshots. It shouldn't be so difficult for the user to perform such a simple common action. IMO this is a big UX blunder.

Comment: How many seconds are you holding the buttons for?

Answer (score 2):

If the buttons don't work, you could always try using ADB from a computer. Root is not required but USB Debugging must be enabled. Then just run:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

These commands will produce a screenshot and save it in the `sdcard` directory (on some devices, including the Nexus line, have an emulated sdcard partition in the internal storage; so don't worry about this), pull to your computer, and then deletes it from your phone.

---

Unfortunately, one would think that this would be easier on stock Android. But that's why so many aftermarket versions or apps exist: to provide the missing functionality that people can cherrypick from and customize as they please. Below is an example of a simpler and nicer interface from which to take screenshots, which was added to stock 4.4.3 Android using [GravityBox [KK]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) (root and [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) required).

[image: screenshotOfScreenshotMenu]

Comment: Aha. So to make a screenshot from the android device, I always need to have it connected to another computer.